Backup (Deja-dup / Duplicity) on 22.04 failed leaving Root volume at 100%
I've used the Backup utility (via Gnome) to backup drives. It has repeatedly failed through lack of space. I've given it more and more Swap space, but it has finally failed leaving working directories clogging up my Root volume.
See below.
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G  6.7M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   54G   51G  343M 100% /
tmpfs                              7.8G  112M  7.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sdc1                          1.8T  1.1T  653G  63% /mnt/backup
/dev/sdb1                          1.8T  5.8G  1.7T   1% /mnt/sparedisk
/dev/sdd1                          3.6T  466G  3.0T  14% /media
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  264M  1.6G  15% /boot
/dev/sda1                          1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              1.6G  3.2M  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
What's the solution here please?
How should I clean up my volume?
I didn't keep the error trace from Deja-Dup, so I can't quote that (unless I dig back through logs, I guess), but I shan't be using Backup again as I can't get it to work and there must be good alternatives.
Thanks in advance. I'll try to find a display of the offending file and post as an addition.
edit: Added screenshot.

edit: Added screenshot of cache


Thanks for reply. Backup destination was a fresh drive and Duplicity has been writing to it.

So how do I clear out that 28Gb of cache that Duplicity has left behind? I tried logging off and on again, but that had no effect.

In the listing above, the backup destination is /mnt/sparedisk

I've figured it out. I think. With the help of a Brave bot, I have moved the cache from the home drive to an underused M2 drive and linked to it. I also deleted the mess that Duplicity left behind when it failed. No further help needed. Thanks.

I am glad that you figured it out. It will be wonderful if you Answer your own question and describe exactly what you did and which commands you used.

With the help of a Brave bot, I have moved the cache from the home drive to an underused M2 drive and linked to it. I also deleted the mess that Duplicity left behind when it failed. No further help needed.
Commands used (using sudo):
mkdir [new cache on M2 drive]
mv [.cache to new location on M2 drive]
ln -s [new cache from old cache].
rm [28gb of files in cache left by Duplicity]
rmdir [old Duplicity directory in cache]

What I hadnt realised when I installed Ubuntu (first-timer) was that it would use the 120Gb installation SSD as its default location for some very large directories, such as cache and swap. I have replaced the Swap directory (using Swapon and Swapoff commands) with a Swap partition (actually the other half of the M2 drive mentioned above). The Ubuntu home drive now has plenty of spare space.
